# Make sure a laptop never shuts down

Tags: windows, shutdown

I have a very strange problem.
When I shut down my laptop (frequently) I can't turn it up for a few days.
I'm 100% sure there is electricity and I've even opened my laptop to have a look inside.
I thought I might have forgotten to put something together the last time I opened it.

Now I'd like to make my laptop only go into stand by mode or restart. It should not be  possible to shut down any more.

Is there a way?

Comment: Use the default power mangement tools to acomplish what happens when the lid is closed and the power button is pressed.

Comment: If the battery dies, it will shut down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the battery icon in your taskbar

Go to power options

And modify the settings from there.

You can alter what happens when you shut the lid, length of time before the screen goes dark etc.

Be sure to change the settings for both when plugged in and unplugged.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that quite what i was looking for. But do you know maybe how to change the function behind the "Shut down" in the "Start" (Taskbar) so that it will to restart or stand by?

Comment: @derty - You can't change that behavior.